# Result of 'getChannelData' through 'MediaElementSourceNode' and 'ScriptProcessorNode' is always zero with iOS (both Safari and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari, web-audio-api

I'd like to record some sounds and process their raw data with iOS and Javascript. So I'm planning to use Web Audio techniques, but `ScriptProcessorNode` or `getChannelData` won't work well.

I put my sample code at the end of this post. It is expected to display in the textarea the raw audio data of the movie file you choose. Although it works correctly with Chrome or Firefox in Windows, it shows only zeros when I use iOS (both Safari and Chrome).

If I use `OscillatorNode` instead of `MediaElementSourceNode`, it works well. Therefore, I'm suspecting using `MediaElementSourceNode` and `ScriptProcessorNode` at the same time but I'm at a loss how to deal this problem.

Sorry for my poor English.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext || window.msAudioContext;
    var rawdata;
    var bufsize = 4096;

    function onaudproc(e) {
        var input   = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        var output  = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        var buf = new Float32Array(bufsize);
        for(var i=0; i<bufsize; i++)    buf[i] = output[i] = input[i];
        Array.prototype.push.apply(rawdata, buf);
    }

    function    filechanges()
    {
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL($('#camfile')[0].files[0]);
        var fn  = function(){
            $('#video').on('ended pause',function(){
            $('#console').append(rawdata.toString());
                $('#video').off();
            });
            $('#writebtn').click(function(){
                audctx  = new AudioContext();
                var spnode = audctx.createScriptProcessor(bufsize, 1, 1);
                var src = audctx.createMediaElementSource($('#video')[0]);
                src.connect(spnode);
                spnode.onaudioprocess = onaudproc;
                spnode.connect(audctx.destination);
                rawdata = [];
                $('#video')[0].play();
            });
        };
        $('#video').on('loadstart',fn);
        $('#video').attr('src',url);
    }

    //]]>
    </script></head>
    <body>
    <div class="buttonset">
    <input type="file" id="camfile" onchange="filechanges()" />
    <input type="button" id="writebtn" value="output" />
    </div>
    <div><video src="#none" id="video" controls="controls" /></div>
    <div><textarea id="console" rows="20" cols="80" /></div>
    </body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a CORS access issue. You need permissions (with recent versions of Chrome) for `createMediaElementSource` to access the data.